# Read value from a Savon response?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, watir, savon

I want to read the value of `customer.customer_info_id` from the following response. My response also includes namespaces:

```
<Field name="customer.customer_id" value="5403699387967341892"/>
<Field name="**customer.customer_info_id**" value="5403699387967341892"/>
<Field name="customer.customer_since_code" value="1985">
    <Lookup language="EN" value="1985"/>
    <Lookup language="FR" value="1985"/>
</Field>
```

I tried the following:

```
# Savon code tried:        

doc = Nokogiri::XML(response.to_xml)
doc.remove_namespaces!
val = doc.xpath("//Field:name" => "Customer.entity_id").to_s
puts "val is: #{val}"
```

It returns null value.

Comment: <Field name="customer.customer_id" value="5403699387967341892"/> <Field name="customer.customer_info_id" value="5403699387967341892"/> <Field name="customer.customer_since_code" value="1985"> <Lookup language="EN" value="1985"/> <Lookup language="FR" value="1985"/> </Field>

I tried the following:
 reader =  Nokogiri::XML::Reader(response.to_xml) 
    val = reader.attribute("customer.customer_id")
       puts "val is #{val}"

It gives me nil value

Comment: Which value do you want to read? Where is your Ruby code? Usually you code something like result.to_hash[:key][:another_key]

Comment: I Want to read the value of customer.customer_info_id.
sorry, code now I posted above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code using Nokogiri worked out to read a particular xml element value:

```
doc=Nokogiri.XML(File.open(File.dirname("your file name here"))

element=doc.at('element_name') #fetch the value of element needed.
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's necessary to parse the XML response. Savon does it for you.
You didn't provide the code for the call so **I assume** it will be *soap*.

```
client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.document = <your url>
end

response = client.request :wsdl, :soap do
  <your parameters go here>
end

# pp response.to_hash

result = response.to_hash[:soap_response][:soap_result][:customer][:customer_info_id]
```

I often use `pp response.to_hash` to get an idea what's returned.

Comment: hi the below code worked out to read to a particular xml element value:

Answer (score 0):

I have had mixed results with Savon. Eventually the WSDL I'm dealing with returns a `StringWithAttributes` class that requires parsing, but until that it should behave like a normal hash meaning you should be able to just do something like:

```
client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.document = <your url>
end

response = client.request(:whatever_the_request_is_called) do
  soap.body = { <hash of your parameters> }
end

result = response[:soap_response][:soap_result][:customer][:customer_info_id]
```

If you're still getting null values, try a `pp response[:soap_response].class` or `.keys` on each level to make sure you're still working with a hash. If it becomes the weird `StringwithAttributes` class you'll have to parse it. This seems to happen after going down to many levels. In that case you can do something like this:

```
needs_parsing = response.to_hash[:soap_response][:soap_result]

parsed = Nori.parse(needs_parsing)
```

Then you should be back to a navigable hash, which you can check with `.class`.